# Queueing one TFS build from another

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm trying to queue one build from inside another build, in order to use some common functionality.

The target build runs fine when started from Visual Studio alone, but when I start it from inside the other some variables seems to tag along and those make my build do crazy things and fail.

I am using the RunWorkflow activity from `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Lab.Workflow.Activities` and I have BuildController, LabEnvronmentUri and ProjectName set to Null since it's from the same controller, agent and project I'm trying to run a build.

`<mtlwa:RunWorkflow BuildController="{x:Null}" LabEnvironmentUri="{x:Null}" ProjectName="{x:Null}" BuildDefinition="[PostBuildBuild]" DisplayName="Run PostBuildBuild executor" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" />`

The new build (the target) starts but fails because it inherits variables or something from the calling workflow.

`Exception Message: There is no working folder mapping for $/Welfare_Research_2009/Source/EduRelease/R140829/Components/WE.EDU.Components.sln. (type ItemNotMappedException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.GetLocalItemForServerItem(String serverItem, Boolean detectImplicitCloak)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.ConvertWorkspaceItem.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
`

The WE.EDU.Components.sln is the project built in the first build, no project is built in the second although the processtemplate contains a build task but no project is inserted so it should skip that.

Is there any way to make RunWorkflow not inherit variables or is there any other activity I can use?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you have a code example or the actual error message?

Comment: Added more info in the question.